# Comparisons of items in a list

Tags: f#, types, mono

I have written this method which given a number and a list will return a new list with the number inserted into the list at the correct position based on its value. (I'm doing an Insertion sort.)

```
let rec insertinto number numbers =
  match numbers with
  | [] -> [number]
  | head::tail -> if head > number then number::numbers else head::(insertinto number tail)
```

F# guesses the type of this method to be :

```
val insertinto : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list when 'a : comparison
```

If I test this method with

```
[4; 10; 15] |> insertinto 12
```

I get

```
val it : int list = [4; 12; 10; 15]
```

Which is clearly wrong. The comparison 'head > number' is not working correctly.

To get it to work I have to specify the type of the numbers parameter :

```
let rec insertinto number numbers: int list =
```

Then it all works, but I dont want to use an int list all the time, I want this to work with any type of list. As long as the type implements comparison it should work, surely.

Why would this work with an int list and not a generic list? What am I missing?

**edit**

ok, this appears to be a Mono only problem.

Comment: Works for me...  What platform are you using?

Comment: Your original function, without the type declaration, works fine for me. By chance, are you doing this in Visual Studio with fsi? I like to use Visual Studio, select text, and use alt-enter to send it to the fsi window -- occasionally, however, I have an error, I update it in the VS editor but forget to send it back to fsi again, so the two are out of sync and might be a little jarring when you re-execute functions in fsi (especially first thing on monday mornings). Can you reliably reproduce the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: That's interesting. I am doing this in Monodevelop on a Mac.

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour described in the question using F# 2.0.0 with mono 2.6.7 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Does it behave correctly if you try compiling and running this code?

Comment: Yes. It works when compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested the code on Mac using Mono (version 2.8) and MonoDevelop with the latest F# integration and the first function (without type annotations) works as expected.

However, I wouldn't be too surprised if this was a bug in earlier version of Mono. There were all sorts of issues in 2.6.x. Giving incorrect result is weird error (more common was some error message or crash), but it may be caused by some issue. Can you check your version of Mono?

I'm using this and it works fine:

```
fsmac:~ tomaspetricek$ mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 2.8 (tarball Thu Oct  7 12:23:27 MDT 2010)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
```

Although you can *run* F# on Mono 2.6.x, it is highly recommended to use 2.8 (which fixes many issues with generics that were blocking for F#)

Comment: Ah that explains things. I was on 2.6.7. An update has sorted it. (btw it is a great honour to have you fix my problem, I am thoroughly enjoying your Functional Programming book at the minute! Am learning a lot from it. Thanks :) )